# ACR 122u NFC reader doesn't connect via USB: return error

Tags: c#, nfc, smartcard, rfid

Im developing a NFC reading system with C#, according to given sample codes with SDK I cannot connect the device with the application. Sometimes it return unknown error code **(-2146434967)** which is not handled in the sample application codes.
[image]

But sometimes it return error code **6**, which is a constant `public const int SCARD_SPECIFIC = 6;` and describe as

```
/*===============================================================
    ' This value implies the card has been reset and specific 
    ' communication protocols have been established.
 '===============================================================*/
```

[image]

I don't know how to proceed, does somebody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contacted ACS team member and found some answers.

For the error 'retCode=6', please do the following steps:

1. Go to Build->Configuration Manager
2. Under 'Active solution platform', select 'New' (if x86 does not exists)
3. Set 'Type or select the new platform:' to "x86"
4. Set "Copy settings from:" to ""
5. Check the 'Create new project platforms'
6. Click 'OK' and rebuild the solution.

For the error 'retCode=-2146434967', it means that the smart card has been removed on the reader.

I've tried this with C#. Ive described on my blog : 
[Simple NFC reading system for windows](https://iranthajayasekara.com/blog/nfc-card-reading-system-with-acr122u-reader.html)

I used Mifare classic 1K Tags. Hope someone will take the advantage.

Thanks

Comment: plus you must click "Connect" before "Get ATR" even if it's clickable after "Initialize"